# Piping Multiple Numbers into Sed

Tags: sed, pipe

Is it possible to pipe a list of numbers into sed?

The pipeline I currently have looks something like:

```
grep -nP 'foo' file_full.txt | sort | awk -F'[:;\t]' '{print $1,$3,$9,$13}'
```

The output of this:

```
2374 213 MID=212 GO=1
2462 213 MID=477 GO=137
2394 233 MID=232 GO=1
2464 233 MID=668 GO=1070
2185 24 MID=23 GO=1
2465 24 MID=752 GO=1083
2146 48 MID=354 GO=1010
1893 48 MID=47 GO=1
2219 58 MID=57 GO=1
2463 58 MID=595 GO=1057
```

My main goal here is to look at $2 for identical values then compare their $4 or GO values. The line with the larger GO value needs to be deleted.

When I add: `sed 's/GO=/& /' | sort -k2,2 -k5n | awk 'a[$2]++ {sub(/GO= /,"GO="); print $1}'`to the previous pipeline I get:

```
2462
2464
2465
2146
2463
```

Which is a list of line numbers I wish to remove from file_full.txt

I know `sed -i '2462d;2464d;2465d;2146d;2463d' file_full.txt` would work but I am unsure how to pipe each of those numbers from above into one sed command.

Am I missing something?

---

Raw data:

```
#CHROM  POS     ID      REF     ALT     QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  i0      i1      i2      i3      i4      i5      i6      i7      i8      i9      i10     i11     i12     i13     i14
1       1       .       A       T       1000    PASS    MID=0;S=0.0324764;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1;MT=0;AC=200;DP=1000 GT      1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1
1       2       .       A       T       1000    PASS    MID=1;S=0.0125739;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1;MT=5;AC=200;DP=1000 GT      1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1
1       3       .       A       T       1000    PASS    MID=2;S=-0.0693919;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1;MT=9;AC=200;DP=1000        GT      1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1
1       4       .       A       T       1000    PASS    MID=3;S=0.0611535;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1;MT=12;AC=200;DP=1000        GT      1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1
1       5       .       A       T       1000    PASS    MID=4;S=-0.0791182;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1;MT=16;AC=200;DP=1000       GT      1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1
1       6       .       A       T       1000    PASS    MID=5;S=0.0463103;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1;MT=21;AC=200;DP=1000        GT      1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1
1       7       .       A       T       1000    PASS    MID=6;S=0.0509527;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1;MT=25;AC=200;DP=1000        GT      1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1
1       8       .       A       T       1000    PASS    MID=7;S=-0.0134404;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1;MT=28;AC=200;DP=1000       GT      1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1
1       9       .       A       T       1000    PASS    MID=8;S=-0.00478324;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1;MT=32;AC=200;DP=1000      GT      1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1
1       10      .       A       T       1000    PASS    MID=9;S=0.03588;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1;MT=36;AC=200;DP=1000  GT      1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1
1       11      .       A       T       1000    PASS    MID=10;S=-0.028843;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1;MT=41;AC=200;DP=1000       GT      1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1
1       12      .       A       T       1000    PASS    MID=11;S=-0.0832497;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1;MT=45;AC=200;DP=1000      GT      1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1
1       13      .       A       T       1000    PASS    MID=12;S=0.0389281;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1;MT=48;AC=200;DP=1000       GT      1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1
1       14      .       A       T       1000    PASS    MID=13;S=0.0362106;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1;MT=53;AC=200;DP=1000       GT      1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1
1       15      .       A       T       1000    PASS    MID=14;S=0.0375309;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1;MT=57;AC=200;DP=1000       GT      1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1
1       16      .       A       T       1000    PASS    MID=15;S=0.0112808;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1;MT=60;AC=200;DP=1000       GT      1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1
1       17      .       A       T       1000    PASS    MID=16;S=0.0243286;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1;MT=65;AC=200;DP=1000       GT      1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1
1       18      .       A       T       1000    PASS    MID=17;S=0.0596463;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1;MT=69;AC=200;DP=1000       GT      1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1
1       24      .       A       T       1000    PASS    MID=23;S=-0.0086571;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1;MT=92;AC=199;DP=1000;MULTIALLELIC GT      1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1
1       58      .       A       T       1000    PASS    MID=57;S=-0.0926969;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1;MT=229;AC=198;DP=1000;MULTIALLELIC        GT      1|1     0|1     1|1     1|1     0|1     1|1
1       213     .       A       T       1000    PASS    MID=212;S=-0.0925562;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1;MT=848;AC=196;DP=1000;MULTIALLELIC       GT      1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1
1       233     .       A       T       1000    PASS    MID=232;S=-0.0868037;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1;MT=929;AC=199;DP=1000;MULTIALLELIC       GT      1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1
1       213     .       A       T       1000    PASS    MID=477;S=0.0600971;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1037;MT=849;AC=4;DP=1000;MULTIALLELIC       GT      0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0
1       58      .       A       T       1000    PASS    MID=595;S=0.0450203;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1057;MT=228;AC=2;DP=1000;MULTIALLELIC       GT      0|0     1|0     0|0     0|0     1|0     0|0
1       233     .       A       T       1000    PASS    MID=668;S=-0.0447337;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1070;MT=928;AC=1;DP=1000;MULTIALLELIC      GT      0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0
1       24      .       A       T       1000    PASS    MID=752;S=-0.104791;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1083;MT=93;AC=1;DP=1000;MULTIALLELIC        GT      0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0
```

Comment: You may not want to read from the file while sed is trying to edit the file...

Comment: Added actual awk and sed commands to my question, hopefully it is makes more sense.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the original data. There may well be easier ways to get to this point or even to do the whole thing in one go.

Comment: Added raw file data and currently trying to fix the numbers I posted before (ie 2463) as they wont correspond to this mini-input file.

Comment: Ah! A vcf! I thought these looked familiar! While this is completely on topic here, you might want to consider asking on [bioinformatics.se] in future since there are probably nifty ways of doing this with domain-specific tools like `bcftools` etc. Also, do you want the entire line of the vcf file? What output are you expecting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a pity we can't see your original data.  Given the result of you pipeline in a file called `file`, you would get the right result though

```
$ sort -t ' ' -k2,2 -k4.4n file | sort -u -k2,2
2374 213 MID=212 GO=1
2394 233 MID=232 GO=1
2185 24 MID=23 GO=1
1893 48 MID=47 GO=1
2219 58 MID=57 GO=1
```

These are the lines in the data with the smallest `GO` value for each group (where the second field defines the group).

The first `sort` sorts the data in such a way that each group's `GO` values are ordered smallest to largest.  That `-k4.4n` *should* have a dot in it, not a comma.  It specifies the actual *value* after the `=` in the fourth field as the secondary sort key.

The second `sort` uses only the group number in the second field and does a unique sort.  This has the effect of only leaving the first line of each unique group in the output.

---

Using the raw data later added to the question:

```
sed 's/\./;./' file |
sort -t ';' -k1,1 -k6.4,6n |
sort -u -t ';' -k1,1 |
sed 's/;\././' |
sort -k1,1n -k2,2n
```

The first two `sort` calls do the same sort of operation as in the earlier part of this answer. Here we use the first two columns (chromosome and position) as the "group key".

The first `sed` replaces the dot in column 3 with `;.`.  This is done to let us use `;` as the field delimiter properly in the two `sort` calls.
The second `sed` calls restores the original dots.

The final `sort` gets the data sorted on chromosomes and position, as from the start.

This results in

```
#CHROM  POS     ID      REF     ALT     QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  i0      i1      i2      i3      i4      i5      i6      i7      i8      i9      i10     i11     i12     i13     i14
1       1       .       A       T       1000    PASS    MID=0;S=0.0324764;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1;MT=0;AC=200;DP=1000 GT      1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1
1       2       .       A       T       1000    PASS    MID=1;S=0.0125739;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1;MT=5;AC=200;DP=1000 GT      1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1
1       3       .       A       T       1000    PASS    MID=2;S=-0.0693919;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1;MT=9;AC=200;DP=1000        GT      1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1
1       4       .       A       T       1000    PASS    MID=3;S=0.0611535;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1;MT=12;AC=200;DP=1000        GT      1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1
1       5       .       A       T       1000    PASS    MID=4;S=-0.0791182;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1;MT=16;AC=200;DP=1000       GT      1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1
1       6       .       A       T       1000    PASS    MID=5;S=0.0463103;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1;MT=21;AC=200;DP=1000        GT      1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1
1       7       .       A       T       1000    PASS    MID=6;S=0.0509527;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1;MT=25;AC=200;DP=1000        GT      1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1
1       8       .       A       T       1000    PASS    MID=7;S=-0.0134404;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1;MT=28;AC=200;DP=1000       GT      1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1
1       9       .       A       T       1000    PASS    MID=8;S=-0.00478324;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1;MT=32;AC=200;DP=1000      GT      1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1
1       10      .       A       T       1000    PASS    MID=9;S=0.03588;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1;MT=36;AC=200;DP=1000  GT      1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1
1       11      .       A       T       1000    PASS    MID=10;S=-0.028843;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1;MT=41;AC=200;DP=1000       GT      1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1
1       12      .       A       T       1000    PASS    MID=11;S=-0.0832497;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1;MT=45;AC=200;DP=1000      GT      1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1
1       13      .       A       T       1000    PASS    MID=12;S=0.0389281;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1;MT=48;AC=200;DP=1000       GT      1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1
1       14      .       A       T       1000    PASS    MID=13;S=0.0362106;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1;MT=53;AC=200;DP=1000       GT      1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1
1       15      .       A       T       1000    PASS    MID=14;S=0.0375309;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1;MT=57;AC=200;DP=1000       GT      1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1
1       16      .       A       T       1000    PASS    MID=15;S=0.0112808;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1;MT=60;AC=200;DP=1000       GT      1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1
1       17      .       A       T       1000    PASS    MID=16;S=0.0243286;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1;MT=65;AC=200;DP=1000       GT      1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1
1       18      .       A       T       1000    PASS    MID=17;S=0.0596463;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1;MT=69;AC=200;DP=1000       GT      1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1
1       24      .       A       T       1000    PASS    MID=23;S=-0.0086571;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1;MT=92;AC=199;DP=1000;MULTIALLELIC GT      1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1
1       58      .       A       T       1000    PASS    MID=57;S=-0.0926969;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1;MT=229;AC=198;DP=1000;MULTIALLELIC        GT      1|1     0|1     1|1     1|1     0|1     1|1
1       213     .       A       T       1000    PASS    MID=212;S=-0.0925562;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1;MT=848;AC=196;DP=1000;MULTIALLELIC       GT      1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1
1       233     .       A       T       1000    PASS    MID=232;S=-0.0868037;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1;MT=929;AC=199;DP=1000;MULTIALLELIC       GT      1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1     1|1
```

---

Extracting *line numbers* that you'd like to delete in a pipeline is often the wrong way to go about a task like this.  Note that each part of a pipeline runs concurrently with every other part of the same pipeline.  This means that you can't start overwriting or modifying a file in one part that you are, at the same, time reading from in another part.

Also note that when extracting data through the stages of a pipeline, you lose the data that you're not passing on.  This makes it even harder to allow the one pipeline to modify the original data (because it's lost along the way through the pipeline).

The solution is therefore not to extract or calculate what should be dropped, but to pass on the bits of the data that should be kept.

Answer (score 4):

You haven't shown the output you expect, but if I understood you correctly, you're looking for something like this (`file` has the data from your question):

```
$ sort -t= -k3 -rn file | awk '{a[$2]=$0}END{for(i in a){print a[i]}}'
2185 24 MID=23 GO=1
1893 48 MID=47 GO=1
2219 58 MID=57 GO=1
2374 213 MID=212 GO=1
2394 233 MID=232 GO=1
```

The idea is to first sort the input on the value of the `GO`. The `-t=` sets `sort`'s field separator to `=`, which makes the number after `GO` the 3rd field. We sort on that, in reverse numerical order so that the larger numbers come first. Then, the `awk` will save each line as a value in the array `a` whose keys are the second fields. Since the file is sorted by the `GO` value, this means we'll always keep the greatest value for each `$2`. Then, at the end of the file we print the array.

---

Alternatively, you can do the whole thing directly from the original file:

```
$ awk -F'[\t=;]' '/^[^#]/{
                    if(!a[$1$2] || a[$1$2]>$17){
                        line[$1$2]=$0; 
                        a[$1$2]=$17
                    }
                   } 
                   END{
                    for(i in a){
                        print line[i]
                    }
                   }' file.vcf 
1   1   .   A   T   1000    PASS    MID=0;S=0.0324764;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1;MT=0;AC=200;DP=1000 GT  1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1
1   2   .   A   T   1000    PASS    MID=1;S=0.0125739;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1;MT=5;AC=200;DP=1000 GT  1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1
1   3   .   A   T   1000    PASS    MID=2;S=-0.0693919;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1;MT=9;AC=200;DP=1000    GT  1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1
1   4   .   A   T   1000    PASS    MID=3;S=0.0611535;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1;MT=12;AC=200;DP=1000    GT  1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1
1   5   .   A   T   1000    PASS    MID=4;S=-0.0791182;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1;MT=16;AC=200;DP=1000   GT  1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1
1   6   .   A   T   1000    PASS    MID=5;S=0.0463103;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1;MT=21;AC=200;DP=1000    GT  1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1
1   7   .   A   T   1000    PASS    MID=6;S=0.0509527;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1;MT=25;AC=200;DP=1000    GT  1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1
1   8   .   A   T   1000    PASS    MID=7;S=-0.0134404;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1;MT=28;AC=200;DP=1000   GT  1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1
1   9   .   A   T   1000    PASS    MID=8;S=-0.00478324;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1;MT=32;AC=200;DP=1000  GT  1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1
1   10  .   A   T   1000    PASS    MID=9;S=0.03588;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1;MT=36;AC=200;DP=1000  GT  1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1
1   11  .   A   T   1000    PASS    MID=10;S=-0.028843;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1;MT=41;AC=200;DP=1000   GT  1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1
1   12  .   A   T   1000    PASS    MID=11;S=-0.0832497;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1;MT=45;AC=200;DP=1000  GT  1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1
1   13  .   A   T   1000    PASS    MID=12;S=0.0389281;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1;MT=48;AC=200;DP=1000   GT  1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1
1   14  .   A   T   1000    PASS    MID=13;S=0.0362106;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1;MT=53;AC=200;DP=1000   GT  1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1
1   15  .   A   T   1000    PASS    MID=14;S=0.0375309;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1;MT=57;AC=200;DP=1000   GT  1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1
1   16  .   A   T   1000    PASS    MID=15;S=0.0112808;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1;MT=60;AC=200;DP=1000   GT  1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1
1   17  .   A   T   1000    PASS    MID=16;S=0.0243286;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1;MT=65;AC=200;DP=1000   GT  1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1
1   18  .   A   T   1000    PASS    MID=17;S=0.0596463;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1;MT=69;AC=200;DP=1000   GT  1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1
1   24  .   A   T   1000    PASS    MID=23;S=-0.0086571;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1;MT=92;AC=199;DP=1000;MULTIALLELIC GT  1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1
1   58  .   A   T   1000    PASS    MID=57;S=-0.0926969;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1;MT=229;AC=198;DP=1000;MULTIALLELIC    GT  1|1 0|1 1|1 1|1 0|1 1|1
1   213 .   A   T   1000    PASS    MID=212;S=-0.0925562;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1;MT=848;AC=196;DP=1000;MULTIALLELIC   GT  1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1
1   233 .   A   T   1000    PASS    MID=232;S=-0.0868037;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1;MT=929;AC=199;DP=1000;MULTIALLELIC   GT  1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1 1|1
```

Here the trick is the `-F'[\t=;]'` which sets awk's input field separator to any of `\t`, `=`, or `;`. That makes the GO value field 17 (assuming all of your lines have the same structure, if they don't, please ask on [Bioinformatics](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com) since that would be better handled with other tools). The rest means:

- `/^[^#]/{ }` : do this on lines that don't start with a `#`.
- `if(a[$1$2]<$17){` : if the value stored in the array `a` for the first and second fields (chromosome and position) is smaller than the 17th field of this line
- `line[$1$2]=$0;` : save this line as the value for the combination of fields 1 and 2 in the array `line`.
- `a[$1$2]=$17` : save the 17th field as the value for the combination of first and  second field in the array `a`.
- `END{for(i in a){print a[i]}}` : just as as above, print the lines.

Now, this will require you to store one entire line for each unique value of the second field. That can be a problem if your file is very large.

One, admittedly inelegant, way of avoiding this issue is to basically do what you originally asked for and use the line numbers. Something like:

```
awk -F'[\t=;]' 'NR==FNR && /^[^#]/{
                    if(!a[$1$2] || a[$1$2]>$17){
                        want[$1$2]=NR; 
                        a[$1$2]=$17
                    }
                } 
                NR!=FNR && want[$1$2]==FNR' file.vcf file.vcf
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe the sed script in through its stdin with the conventional `-` name.  Working off your supplied sample and dropping the unused `$9`,

```
grep -n = full.txt \
| awk -F'[:;\t]' '{sub(/.*=/,"",$13); print $1,$3,$13 }' \
| sort -nk2,3 \
| awk 'last==$2{print $1"d"}last=$2' \
# | sed -i -f- full.txt
```

If you're on a Mac, they've made a backup extension mandatory, you'll have to say `sed -i '' etc` to shut it off.

I figure it's better with a file that promises to be large to do as much data reduction as possible before sorting.

When I sub in `$1"p"` for `$1"d"` and run it through `|sed -nf- full.txt` to print the lines it'd delete I get

```
$ grep -n = full.txt     | awk -F'[:;\t]' '{sub(/.*=/,"",$13); print $1,$3,$13 }'     | sort -nk2,3     | awk 'last==$2{print $1"p"}{last=$2}' | sed -nf- full.txt
1       213     .       A       T       1000    PASS    MID=477;S=0.0600971;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1037;MT=849;AC=4;DP=1000;MULTIALLELIC       GT      0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0
1       58      .       A       T       1000    PASS    MID=595;S=0.0450203;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1057;MT=228;AC=2;DP=1000;MULTIALLELIC       GT      0|0     1|0     0|0     0|0     1|0     0|0
1       233     .       A       T       1000    PASS    MID=668;S=-0.0447337;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1070;MT=928;AC=1;DP=1000;MULTIALLELIC      GT      0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0
1       24      .       A       T       1000    PASS    MID=752;S=-0.104791;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=1083;MT=93;AC=1;DP=1000;MULTIALLELIC        GT      0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0
$
```